# Using groupby to do in-place modification on the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

```
Time(minutes)       ID          start_time     end_time      queue
420                 11            300            400         [00:]
420                 13            400            500         [00:11]
420                 00            200            350         []
421                 11            300            400         [00:]
421                 13            400            500         [00:11]
421                 00            250            300         []
```

I have a dataframe that somewhat looks like this, and then **I want to add all the the durations (end_time - start_time) in the queue using start_time and end_time that is available at that given time**. Note that start_time and end_time is not necessarily fixed. It may change over time. My desired output is:

```
Time(minutes)       ID          start_time     end_time      total_duration
420                 11            300            400         150
420                 13            400            500         250
420                 00            200            350         0
421                 11            300            400         50
421                 13            400            500         150
421                 00            250            300         0
```

Is groupby any good for this kind of problem? Or should I use iterrow() and keep track of change in the minute? The problem is that I need to keep track of start_time and end_time every minute, so ideally I  may need a dictionary to store duration keyed customer ID, but I can't find any useful documentation for groupby to do in-place modification.

Comment: can you explain how you get total_duration using couple rows as an example?

Comment: Sum the duration of ID (customer) in the queue. Duration = end - start time, but you only use times that are given at that minute

Comment: so, how do you get 150 in the first line?

Comment: The queue has an ID is 00, and that persom has duration of 350-200=150 minutes

Comment: what type is `queue`?

Comment: You may assume it is string. I used delimiter : to store it as a list.